# How do I fix duplicate symbol error in iOS project using WindowsAzureMobileServices.framework

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm building my first Azure Mobile Services app on iOS. I'm using Xcode 6.4 and swift. I followed the instructions to download the iOS sdk from the Azure portal and dragged it into my project. Since I'm developing in swift I added a bridging header file with this line in it:

```
#import <windowsazuremobileservices/WindowsAzureMobileServices.h>
```

I pointed to it in the Build Settings under Swift Compiler - Code Generation Objective-C Bridging Header. I think I did that step correctly because it seemed to see the classes and build.

But I get a linking error now when I try to define a var of type MSClient.

```
var client: MSClient?
```

There are many errors like this now:

duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/claritymacbook/Dev/Scavenger Hunt/WindowsAzureMobileServices.framework/WindowsAzureMobileServices(MSClient.o)
    /Users/claritymacbook/Dev/Scavenger Hunt/WindowsAzureMobileServices.framework/WindowsAzureMobileServices(MSDateOffset.o)

I feel like this could either be an error with the framework or just something I'm not doing right because I'm still fairly new to swift and Xcode. Ideas?

Comment: download the new sdk and check once

Comment: did something change in the last 24 hours? (accidentally upvoted comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest build of the framework files require using XCode 7.  If you want to use 6, you can manually build the FW from the source code on Github.  (The duplicate symbols are because of the inclusion of bit code in the fw)

Comment: Is this where you're talking about (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services)? And would I get the latest but build in my Xcode? Is there repository of previous SDKs to download?

Comment: Wait - I think this page with a link to download iOS 1.2.4 SDK might be what I want. I'll try and report back: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/CHANGELOG.ios.md

Comment: I think this was the last build for XCode 6.4: https://zumo.blob.core.windows.net/sdk/azuresdk-iOS-v2.2.1.zip  (2.2.2 is the newest server version)

Comment: 1.2.4 will work, but it has some breaking changes so 2.2.1 is a better choice.

Comment: This version worked! I just had to get rid of the 2 in the folder before referencing it. I've been able to make a call to an API method now. Thanks!